# Get selected objects in the order they were selected

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

With Fabric.js I can one by one select objects by holding the shift key.
How can I access the selected objects in the order they were <s>added</s> selected?

So for example:

```
canvas.getActiveGroup().item(0);
```

should return the first selected object.

```
canvas.getActiveGroup().getObjects();
```

returns the objects in an arbitrary order.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Removed my original answer to make it easier for others reading this.

You should be able to do this with the selection:created event listener:

```
canvas.on('selection:created', function(options) {
console.log(options.target._objects);
});
```

Now you can see in the console the items in the order they were added to the selection, and do with them as you please

http://jsfiddle.net/DanBrown180/Zmn7U/ - shows how to access the data

Dan

Comment: Hi Dan,

thanks for you answer.
It works fine with fabric.js 1.2, but the same jsfiddle fails with fabric.js 1.4.

http://jsfiddle.net/npanasenko/t4axw/1/
(try selecting the green one first...)
Nikolai